# Blocks in a layer? $X$ layers of blocks in a triangle, which $Y$ being the total number of blocks... (w/o using triangular numbers)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have $32$ layers of blocks in a triangle. However, for the sake of variation, let's call that $X$.

I have $1000$ square blocks total. We'll call those $Y$.

The first layer of the triangle has $1$ block (always), maybe the next has $2$ or $3$, etc. until the blocks are all used up in as triangular a figure as possible.

====================================

How can I figure out how many blocks are in each layer in the triangle? Trying to figure this out for a project. Any help is appreciated because I'm totally lost here.

====================================

*EDIT: added detail...*

My apologies. A better definition of "as triangular a figure as possible" would be... as few blocks per layer as possible (across all layers), while still forming a figure resembling triangle. The layers should grow from top to bottom. — In other words, 1 block in each layer then the remaining blocks all totaled in the last layer would fail the first constraint since there's not as few blocks as possible in that last layer, and it also wouldn't resemble a triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines.  In particular, make sure your question is clear. In this case, what do you mean by "as triangular a figure as possible"? I can think of several definitions, each one leading to a different answer to your question.

Comment: My apologies. I just updated it.